# Unable to upload image on mvc 4 web application hosted on windows azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, file-permissions

I have developed a web application using ASP.Net MVC 4, then hosted that web application on windows azure (windowsazure.com).

My website is unable to upload image/create file. Should I add some permissions?or how to add these permissions?

Comment: how did you hosted you application in Windows Azure? Did you use Azure WebSites or Azure Cloud Services? And what you mean by "my websites is unable to upload image" ? Try to better explain the problem, ideally providing code snippets of code that is not working, concrete error messages and configuration settings.

Comment: Thanks.I used Azure WebSites.On signup page of my web application,I submitted a form (@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","User", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))) containing an image,but due to that image my web app is not creating an user.But if dont upload image, then signup process works fine. On server side,the code written for saving image on file system is: <code>string file_name=Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+"-"+Request.Files["profile_picture"].FileName;
string img_path=Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages/"+file_name);
Request.Files["profile_picture"].SaveAs(img_path);<code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Edit question to provide code snippet.
Give the code you've provided, the failing part is most probably the line:

> Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages/" + ...);

What you really have to do, is first check whether that folder already exists:

```
string targetFolder = Server.MapPath("~/UploadImages");
if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists(taretfolder))
{
 System.IO.Directory.Create(targetFolder);
}
// then copy the file here
```

The "problem", if one can say it is a problem at all, is that the server does not have this directory created when you try to put file into it. You have to first the directory before trying to copy files.
And by the way, it is not an "Azure" issue. If you take your code as is and upload it to a hoster (without manually creating or coping the UploadImages folder) you will encounter the very same issues.